# Problems with acessing docker container WildFly hosted application

Tags: docker, wildfly

I am using WildFly 8.2.1 to host my application on my host system with following configuration:

- WildFly is running on `localhost:8080`
- Management console is running on `localhost:9990`

I have my app hosted and accessible with following URL:

```
https://localhost:8081/MyAppRoute
```

I used Docker to send it over to other people but I am havin problems with accessing my application from host environment (keep getting website unreachable).

I am running docker component with following command:

```
docker run -d --name MyApp -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 MyApp
```

I am exposing `8080`, `9990` for WildFly communication (which works fine) and other ports for myApp (doesn't work).

Any ideas what could be the problem? Thats my first app on docker so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: have you set -b 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: @kret where? WildFly or Docker?

Comment: wildfly runtime param